# how many log file types nexus sonatype does release and log format?

Tags: sonatype

I am new to Nexus. Can anyone tell what type of log files Nexus Sona type does release and  log format?. I got different answers from different sources but I am looking for an expert answer with clear details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official logging guide for Nexus 2.x. A comparable guide for NX 3.x will exist at some point in the future.

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464768-Nexus-Logging-Guide